# What is the difference between creating an object with superclass reference and creating an object with subclass reference?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
class C implements Runnable{        
    public void run() {                                         
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread2");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my main thread, I write:

```
C c = new C();
```

which produces the same output as

```
Runnable c=new C();
```

What are the advantages of using either of them?
Is there a general rule when to use which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `C c = new C()`, the type of the variable is of type `C`, whereas with `Runnable c = new C()`, the type of the variable is `Runnable`. For the first case, only instances of type `C` can be stored in the variable. For the second case, instances of a class that implements `Runnable` are allowed.

`Runnable` is a functional interface that is used to pass pieces of runnable code as parameters to methods. Usually, you're always going to use the second case for functional interfaces.

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful, is there a specific reason for going with the second approach for functional interfaces?

Comment: Well, using the second approach adds more flexibility for the variable as it has a broader scope. Typically, functional interfaces are implemented using anonymous classes or lambdas, which do not have a name.